# How many elements in the list, the index of the element clicked

Tags: jquery

Consider the following markup

```
<ul id="thumbs">
    <li><a href=""><img class="thumb" src=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img class="thumb" src=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img class="thumb" src=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

When i click on an img with a class 'thumb', i want the following:

How many list items in the ul list
The index of the list item where the clicked img belongs to

```
$('img.thumb').click(function(e) {
    // how many elements in the list 'thumbs'

    // the index of the <li> where the img clicked belong to
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $('img.thumb').click(function(e) {
   // how many elements in the list 'thumbs'
     alert($('#thumbs li').length);
   // the index of the <li> where the img clicked belong to
     alert($(this).closest('li').index());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `length` to get the total number of list items as well as **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** and **[.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)** to get index of the closest ancestor `li` of clicked image:

```
$('img.thumb').click(function(e) {
    // how many elements in the list 'thumbs'
    var length = $('#thumbs li').length;

    // the index of the <li> where the img clicked belong to
    var index = $(this).closest('li').index();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/26M6j/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('img.thumb').click(function(e) {
  $("#thumbs li").length;
  $(this).closest("li").index();
});
```

You can use either `closest("li")` or `parents("li")` for getting the parent `li` purpose. You can find the index using `index()` method. and `length()` for getting the count